# Dynamically resize outer JPanel depending on JPanels inner JTextPane height

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTextPane` inside a `JPanel`, this `JTextPane` is at runtime being populated with text. I want the `JPanel` that is holding the `JTextPane` to dynamically change in height when `JTextPane` gets more than one line of text.

This is what ive got so far:

```
     pnlChatMsgs = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
     pnlChatMsgs.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(244, 244, 244));
     pnlMainTable.add(pnlChatMsgs, c);


     pnlMidLiveType = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
     pnlMidLiveType.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));

     JTextPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 13));
     JTextPane.setText("<html></html>");
     JTextPane.setContentType("text/html");
     JTextPane.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
     JTextPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 250, 250));
     pnlMidLiveType.add(JTextPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

     pnlChatMsgs.add(pnlMidLiveType, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     pnlMidLiveType.setVisible(false);
```

So when `JTextPane` grows in size i want to change the height of the `pnlMidLiveType` JPanel.

How could i accomplish this?

Comment: You are calling `setPreferredSize()`. The panel will thereafter return that, ignoring the preferred size of the text pane.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example. It demonstrates expandable JFrame and JPanel:

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            frame.pack();
        }
    });
    panel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

JFrame#pack() triggers resize event and does the trick.